# Forward email using EWS managed api keeping the headers

Tags: exchange-server, ews-managed-api

I am looking for a sample code on how to forward an existing email message (one that is already in my inbox) using the managed api.

When forwarded is there some way to keep a message original headers while forwarding it?
for example someone sent an email to me -i would like that ews will forward it to another recipient without changing the headers (original receive time from ,bcc etc...).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given an EmailMessage object, you can just call the CreateForwareMessage() method:

```
var forwareMessage = item.CreateForward();
```

Regarding the other question: Get the MIME content of the mail and attach it to a new message:

```
item.Load(new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, ItemSchema.MimeContent));
var mail = new EmailMessage(service);
var attachment = mail.Attachments.AddFileAttachment("Original message.eml", item.MimeContent.Content);
attachment.ContentType = string.Format("message/rfc822; charset={0}", item.MimeContent.CharacterSet);
mail.ToRecipients.Add("hkrause@infinitec.de");
mail.Subject = "testmail";
mail.SendAndSaveCopy();
```

EDIT:

Create forward message and set reply to header:

```
var fw = item.CreateForward();
var fwMsg = fw.Save(WellKnownFolderName.Drafts);
fwMsg.ReplyTo.Add("personA@company.com");
fwMsg.SendAndSaveCopy();
```

Comment: Thanks hening,am looking for a way that the user who gets the forwarded message can do a reply to the original senders of the forwarded message.

Comment: You mean you forward the mail from person A to person B to person C and person C should be able to reply to person A? Well, you can certainly do that by having person B create a new mail and attach the old one, as I did in the example. Otherwise, create a forward message and set the reply-to header to Person A. See my third example.

Comment: Thanks Henning,am thinking on much simpler case. let me tell you the all scenario it will be much easier -am developping a custom code for this purpose : person a is oof he recieves email the code takes the email as is and forward it to person b person b should see the email as if it were sent directly to him -so he can do a reply to the same recipient that were as they were in the message when sent to recipient a. the key thing here is that the person b should be able to reply the message to the same recipients as if he was recipinet a.

Comment: Well, you could do that by setting the ReplyTo property as outlined in my example. Another option would be to copy the mail message to the inbox of the delegate.

Comment: If the answer was helpful, please mark the answer accordingly. This will help other uthers with similar problems.